# LinearLayout Android put elements inline horizontal

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a list of elements inside a `Linear Layout` with **horizontal** orientation. I need that this elements move to next row when the size exceeds the width of the screen. (*Like float left elements in CSS*)

[image]

Some of this elements will be hidden in runtine so I don't want make **nested layouts** or **TableLayout** solution. Can someone recommend me something to solve this?

I was reading and found this library: https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout But I would prefer use android sdk code if possible

Comment: Have you considered a RecyclerView with the GridLayoutManager? I think it should do this.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using RecyclerView or ScrollView.

Comment: I will try today. Thanks